# How to Update the data in a SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

So, I have my SQLite DataBase set-up, but now I want to know how can I make data update if a certain name already exist. For example, my app has the user input the name of a chore or errand. Then I have the user input information about this chore or errand such as priority, and time needed to complete the task. And when the user clicks a "create activity" button, my code creates a button with the name of the chore as its text. And I have my app set-up where the user can click on this chore button, and it will show the information that was entered in for this specific chore. It leads the user to another activity in which the user can change the information about the chore(such as priority and time needed), but it doesn't allow them to change the name of the chore. And so, when the user clicks on a button saying "update", I want my data base to identify the chore by its name, and replace every other variable. I have looked up other post on this question, and I have found satisfying answers, but I can not figure out the odd syntax that is needed to write a SQlite method. I saw a post that says this code is how you would update data:

```
 INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Employee (id, role, name) 
 VALUES (  1, 
        'code monkey',
        (SELECT name FROM Employee WHERE id = 1)
      );
```

But, I'm a beginner to using a SQLite database, and so I'm confused on what the whole method code would look like. Could you post an update method code that uses name, timeNeeded, and priority as the columns, and mytable as the table name. I need the code to identify the data set by the name, and update the other data. Please include the parameters, complete syntax, and return code if needed. This is code I was able to come up with when I tried to create my own update code:

```
 public void UpdateData(String activityName,int priority, int leastTime)
{
    String sql="UPDATE "+TABLE_NAME+ " SET priority='"+priority+"' ,leastTime='"+leastTime+"' ,activityName='"+activityName;
    db.execSQL(sql);


}
```

Comment: Check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29 and learn how to use the update() method properly. You will find more with a quick search in SO.

Comment: First, you execute a simple query on the PK (activityName?). Then, check if the ResultSet contains entries, see ResultSetMetaData for that. If it contains 0 rows, you have to INSERT it, if it contains 1 row, you need to UPDATE the entry.

Comment: Would I be using something along the lines of content.put(PRIORITY, priority);

Comment: or something with a string syntax like i posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,

This line contains some errors (the integers are enclosed in **'** and the final string hasn't the closing **'**):

```
String sql="UPDATE "+TABLE_NAME+ " SET priority='"+priority+"' ,leastTime='"+leastTime+"' ,activityName='"+activityName;
```

It should be:

```
String sql="UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET priority = " + priority + ", leastTime = " + leastTime + ", activityName = '"+activityName + "'";
```

Second, it would be **much better**, if you bind your parameters, as in:

```
String sql="UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET priority = ?, leastTime = ?, activityName = ?";
```

followed by a:

```
db.execSQL(sql, new String[]{priority, leastTime, activityName});
```

? are simply placeholders for the passed array of values, which will automatically converted to the proper datatypes.
This is also useful to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: The last line(db.execSQL) inquires a String array, but I have leastTime as an integer, so what should I do with that?

Comment: Maybe you didn't read my answer fully: `? are placeholders for the passed array of values, which will automatically converted to the proper datatypes` - integers will be converted to integers.

Comment: Ohhh, okay I see what your saying now, so I should change all my parameters coming in as Strings, then when I put it in the String array, they will change automatically.

Comment: Not when you put them in the string array (they are converted to strings at that time), but `execSQL()` does the work for you.

Comment: So, how I incorporate something like, "activityName LIKE '%"+name+"%'" this way it identifies the activity by the name, and then updates?

Comment: `... Like ?`" and then in the string array, use `..., "%" + activityName + "%"});`